# Passing Hidden Form Data in a session post

Tags: php, webforms

I have to submit this form to a payment processing gateway on my PHP page. All the credit card payment information will be taken on the next screen but the gateway needs the "HostedKey" and "Gateway_ID" need to be invisible from public code view as well.

```
<form action="nextpage.php" method ="POST" target="_blank">
Patient Account Number:
<input type="text" name="CustRefID" id="CustRefID">

<input type="hidden" name="HostedKey" id="HostedKey" value="ZZZZZZ" />
<input type="hidden" name="Gateway_ID" id="Gateway_ID" value="XXXXXX" />

<input type="hidden" name="IndustryCode" id="IndustryCode" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="Amount" id="Amount" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="RecurringType" id="RecurringType" value="N" />
<input type="hidden" name="RecurringAmount" id="RecurringAmount" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="CURL" id="CURL" value="back to my site" />
<input type="hidden" name="AVSRequired" id="AVSRequired" value="Y"/>
<input type="hidden" name="CVV2Required" id="CVV2Required"value="Y"/>
<input type="hidden" name="EmailRequired" id="EmailRequired" value="Y"/>
<input type="hidden" name="PostRspMsg" id="PostRspMsg" value="Y"/>
<input type="hidden" name="SECCode" id="SECCode"  value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="Descriptor" id="Descriptor" value="Online" />
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Pay Online Now" />
</form>
```

I tried something like this. It hid the Key and ID but the form did not pass on the hidden session variables.

```
<strong>Patient Account Number: </strong>
<form action="nextpage.php" method"post">
<input type="text" name="CustRefID"/>
<input type="hidden" name="HostedKey" id="HostedKey" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="Gateway_ID" value="<?php ($Gateway_ID); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="HostedKey" value="<?php ($HostedKey); ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{ $_session['CustRefID'] = $_POST['CustRefID'];} 
{ $_session['HostedKey'] = $_POST['xxxxxx'];} 
{ $_session['Gateway_ID'] = "zzzzzz";} 

?> 

<strong><? echo $_session['CustRefID'];?></strong>
```

Any help would be great. My programmer is out sick...

Comment: 'view source' those values will never be hidden, and shouldn't matter. you will have to identify your self to the payment gateway some how, and that's not a security issue

Comment: If you view source on this file it does show the fields I am trying to hide. http://clients.fai2.com/stackflow/form.php

Comment: you cant hide them, you don't need to hide them. there is no problem here

Comment: My clients vendor is asking for this change. When you say you can't hide these values. How would you do this. I understand you don't think I would need to, but I do.

Comment: send your client to me, as im doing the work, i should get paid.

Comment: As this is my first time on stackoverflow, I would like to thank you for being so gracious and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have repetition in your HTML. Change it to this:

`<input type="hidden" name="Gateway_ID" value="<?php ($Gateway_ID); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="HostedKey" value="<?php ($HostedKey); ?>" />`

2. You didn't specify what POST info should go in the SESSION. Change it to this:

    `{
    $_SESSION['CustRefID'] = $_POST['CustRefID']; 
    $_SESSION['HostedKey'] = $_POST['HostedKey']; 
    $_SESSION['Gateway_ID'] = $_POST['HostedKey'];
    }`